# Enviar value de option select a href

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-select

El tema es el siguiente. Tengo una tabla que se carga a través de una base de datos.
Dicha tabla, tiene en su penúltima columna un Select Option (que se carga desde mysql) y en su ultima columna, un botón que debería enviar los datos a otra pagina para ser procesados. La primera parte del codigo es:

```
 $consulta = "SELECT id, nombre, codigo FROM imputables WHERE estado = 'S' AND id_cl = '$id_cl' AND empresa = 2 ";
 $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
 $cuentas= array();
 while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
  $cuentas[] = $row;
 }
```

Este código genera un array con todas las cuentas contables asociadas a la empresa 2. 
La parte donde cargo el select option y el boton es el siguiente:

```
<table id="export_to_excel" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ITEM</th>
   <th>FECHA SOL</th>
   <th>TIPO DOC</th>
   <th>N° DOC</th>
   <th>RUT PROV</th>
   <th>CENTRO COSTO</th>
   <th>FINALIDAD GASTO</th>
   <th>MONTO ORIGINAL</th>
   <th>MONTO APROBADO</th>
   <th>CTA. CONTABLE</th>
   <th>APLICAR</th>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>$<b><?=$tot?></b></td>
    <td>$<b><?=$tot1?></b></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
   $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
   $conexion->query("SET @index:=0");
   $consulta =  "SELECT

   @index:=@index+1 AS 'index',
   det.id AS id_det,
   det.fecha_compra,
   td.nombre AS tipo_doc,
   det.rut,
   cc.nombre AS centro_costo,
   det.concepto,
   det.monto,
   det.monto_nuevo,
   det.n_doc,
   fdr.folio_gral,
   fdr.fecha_autorizacion,
   det.reparos,
   det.monto_nuevo,
   det.obs_aut_cont,
   det.estado_aprobacion,
   det.id_cuenta

   FROM det_fdr det

   INNER JOIN fdr ON fdr.id = $id_fdr
   INNER JOIN tipo_doc_fdr td ON td.id = det.tipo_doc
   INNER JOIN centro_costo cc ON cc.id = det.c_costo

   WHERE det.id_fdr = '$id_fdr' AND det.id_cl = '$id_cl' AND det.estado = 'S' ";
   $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
   if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
   while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
    $fecha_sol = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['fecha_autorizacion']));
    $tipo_doc = strtoupper($row['tipo_doc']);
    $n_doc = $row['n_doc'];

    $ci = $row['rut'];
    $dig = substr($ci,strlen($ci)-1,1);
    $dig = strtoupper($dig);
    $rut = number_format(substr($ci,0,strlen($ci)-1),0,".",".")."-".$dig;

    $cc = strtoupper($row['centro_costo']);
    $concepto = strtoupper($row['concepto']);
    $montox = $row['monto'];

    if($row['estado_aprobacion'] == 'N'){
     $monto = 0;
    }

    if($row['estado_aprobacion'] == 'A'){
     $monto = $row['monto_nuevo'];
    }

    if($row['estado_aprobacion'] == 'R'){
     $monto = $row['monto_nuevo'];
    }
               
    $id_prueba[] = $row['id_det'];
    $total_array[] = $row['monto_nuevo'];

    if($row['obs_aut_cont'] == 'N'){
     $obs_aut = 'SIN OBSERVACIONES';
    }else{
     $obs_aut = strtoupper($row['obs_aut_cont']);
    }

    $id_cuenta = $row['id_cuenta'];

    ?>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:50px"><?=$row['index']?></td>
     <td width="100"><?=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['fecha_compra']))?></td>
     <td width="100"><?=$tipo_doc?></td>
     <td style="width:80px"><?=$n_doc?></td>
     <td style="width:80px"><?=$rut?></td>
     <td><?=$cc?></td>
     <td><?=$concepto?></td>
     <td align="right" >$<?=number_format($montox, 0, ',', '.')?></td>
     <td align="right" >$<?=number_format($monto, 0, ',', '.')?></td>
     <td style="width:220px">
      <select class='form-control select2 opcion' name='opcion' id="opcion" required>
       <option value='' selected='selected' disabled>SELECCIONE CUENTA</option>

      <?php

       foreach($prueba as $dns) {

        if($id_cuenta == $dns[0]){
         echo "<option value='".$dns['id']."' selected>".$dns['codigo']. " --> " .utf8_encode(strtoupper($dns['nombre']))."</option>";
        }else{
         echo "<option value='".$dns['id']."'>".$dns['codigo']. " --> " .utf8_encode(strtoupper($dns['nombre']))."</option>";
        }

       }

       ?>

       </select>

       </td>
       <td><a href='cerrar_exe.php' onclick="location.href = this.href+'?opt='+ObtenerValor()+-<?php echo $row['id_det']?>; return false;" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">APLICAR</a></td>

      </tr>
      <?php } } ?>

     </tbody>
    </table>
```

La función ObtenerValor() es la siguiente:

```
function ObtenerValor() {
 var valor = document.getElementById("opcion").value;
 return valor;
}
```

El código si bien funciona solo envía los datos (value) del primer select independiente de cualquier select option que se elija.

Adjunto imagen de como se ve la tabla en el lado del cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si falta información que ayude a solucionar el problema, la entregaré a la brevedad posible.
Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Hola. No uses etiquetas HTML en la redacción de la pregunta, usa espacios, como si estuvieras en un editor de texto. Dicho eso, no se entiende muy bien la pregunta. ¿El problema es con el botón que dice `APLICAR`? Si es eso, muestra el código donde produces los botones `APLICAR`. Has mostrado sólo la cabecera, pero no dónde se generan los botones para cada fila.

Comment: @A.Cedano, Hola. Sorry por lo de las etiquetas.
El problema como explique (o al menos traté) en la pregunta, es que independiente de que fila seleccione, siempre me envia el value del primer select de la tabla. No puse la tabla completa ya que es muy extensa y en su mayoria solo trae datos informativos. De hecho el codigo del botón esta en al ultima linea th.

Comment: No me refiero a que pongas la tabla completa, sino el código que genera la tabla. ¿Acaso todos los botones se generan llamando a `ObtenerValor()`? Si es así, es normal que tome siempre el mismo valor, porque nada cambia en esa función, en ella alcanzas siempre el mismo elemento llamando a `getElementById("opcion")`. Por favor, pon todo el código que genera la tabla pulsando en [edit].

Comment: @A.Cedano pregunta fue editada. Saludos y gracias por cualquier ayuda u orientacion.

Comment: Sigue faltando información en el código. Por ejemplo, ¿de dónde a la variable `$prueba` que estás recorriendo en el `foreach` para construir la tabla?

Comment: Tampoco se entiende mucho qué es lo que intentas en esta última celda: `<td><a href='cerrar_exe.php'...` y sigues sin especificar si el problema es ese botón, o si es el `select` o cuál es el problema. Prueba a crear esa última celda así: `printf('<td><a href="cerrar_exe.php" onclick="location.href = this.href?opt=%s; return false;" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">APLICAR</a></td>',$row['id_det']);` Eso hará que cada `href` tenga el valor `opt=` más el valor de `$row['id_det']`. Pues como te comenté más arriba, no veo cuál sea el sentido de llamar a `ObtenerValor()` en ese contexto.

Comment: Tal como indicaron, ten siempre presente que [los id deben ser únicos en el DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que todos tus selects se llaman option por eso te trae el primero lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

Primero al tr le agregas un id puede ser el de la cuenta

```
$id_cuenta = $row['id_cuenta'];
?>
    <tr id="$id_cuenta">
.......
```

Ya con esto en el boton no le pongas el href ponle una funcion que va hacer la funcion del href y le pasas el id

```
onclick="redirigir($id_cuenta)"
```

Luego en la funcion ya sabes de que linea quieres obtener el valor

```
function redirigir(id_cuenta){
  var opcion =  document.getElementById(id_cuenta).getElementsByName('opcion')[0].value
location.href = this.href+'?opt=' + opcion
}
```